# Destroying Tokens/Coins in a Smart Contract

Tags: currency, bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm currently doing a project attempting to developing a currency and model for P2P energy transactions, where every kwh of renewable energy generated mints one coin to that producer. And my question is regarding destroying coins in a smart contract.

All of the current implementations similar to my project don't have a proper protocol for destroying coins that would aim to prevent hyper deflation in its value. Some projects destroy their proposed energy currency through transaction costs and lost wallets but I don't think that's enough. This is because energy coins can be minted at an exponential rate if more and more people begin to adopt the project and use their solar panels and wind farms to mint big amounts of coins. And coins would stay in circulation that represent energy generated (and used) days/weeks/months ago in the past.

I want to propose that you can use these coins to pay the utilities for energy consumption, and this will ultimately destroy those exact coins, which is written in the immutable smart contract that the consumer and energy company will agree upon.

I'm new to computer coding and I don't want to assume one can easily write in a smart contract to say destroy() the specified number of coins. Would it be possible for one to do this and make it work? I think I just need a second opinion!

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 3):

While Samuel solution clearly works, you loose forever track of how many tokens were destroyed. 
I would instead take the user spent tokens and “burn” them, meaning sending them to a 0x address that locks them in forever. 
In this way, just looking at the balance of the 0x address, you can see immediately how many tokens were burn in the history of your smart contract.

Comment: Possibly naive question: Is there a way to prove that the 0x address you are sending the tokens to be burnt is not actually controlled by anyone? Alternatively, what if you just keep a count of the destroyed tokens from the within the contract itself with Samuel's solution? Won't that serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to assume one can easily write in a smart contract to say destroy() the specified number of coins. Would it be possible for one to do this and make it work?

Yes, you can write a method for your contract to destroy tokens. One way to do this would be to remove X amount of tokens from the address count and to then remove X amount of tokens from the total token supply.

With this approach you are effectively destroying the tokens in an elegant way. Sending tokens to "lost accounts" is not a good idea because you can never guarantee or prove that noone controls the private key for that account.

Answer (score 0):

You could also keep all tokens that do not currently represent energy in you contract, and if you cannot issue them, just destroy them by subtracting them using [this]